# How to get the accuracy and precision of Scaled YOLOv4

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, yolov4

This is the github repo that I forked. It is the Scaled YOLOv4 repository. I tried running it, but it doesn't show metrics for accuracy and precision.

https://github.com/WongKinYiu/ScaledYOLOv4/tree/yolov4-csp

Comment: So how did you try to solve this problem so far?

Comment: By running test.py. It showed a value for P, R, mAP. I'm not sure if it is related to accuracy or precision. I know that mAP is the mean average precision.